# error on web browser 'Website not secure'

Tags: heroku, dns, ssl-certificate

I have a application hosted when I visit the site www.mysite.co.uk

Im getting Website Not Secure. Obviously this doesnot look good if users are accessing the site. How Can I fix this?

My application is hosted on heroku

I have added my domain to heroku:

- Domain -> `www.mysite.co.uk`
- DNS -> `www.mysite.co.uk.herokudns.com`
- ACM Staus:`OK`

Heroku also gives me info that "Your app can be found
   at https://www.mysite.co.uk"

And heroku manages the SSL certificate automatically.

The domain however is managed by gandhi.net

And I have configured the DNS to:

```
www CNAME   10800   www.mysite.co.uk.herokudns.com.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the responsibility of the one who offers the domain, because they are the ones who have the servers, in the browsers it appears that it is not safe because they do not have the necessary security certificates to be considered a "secure site".

If the hosting provider tells you that you have to install it, you should ask them how to do it